# PYTHON: Removing list of words from a list

Tags: list, list-comprehension, strip

I have a list of stopwords. And I have a search list. I want to remove the words 
 from the list.
As an example:

I have given my code below. What could I be doing wrong?

```
stopwords=['what','who','and','a','at','is','am']
query=['What is hello','Ask in the community','my name is alan and I am coming 
from London']

querywords = query.split()

resultwords  = [word for word in querywords if word.lower() not in stopwords]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)

print (result)
```

It is given the below Error Code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "python", line 17, in 
>       AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I think you forgot a critical tag...

Comment: @ZoharPeled which means?

Comment: What programming language are you working with?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Python

Comment: It looks like you need query in string, not as a list. it query is a list then use loop, for `query='What is hello','Ask in the community','my name is alan and I am coming 
from London'`

Comment: Split does not exist on list but on string type.

Comment: @TalhaJunaid any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`split` is a string method and does not exist on lists. As `query` represents a string in a list. if you change `query` to string it will work.

```
stopwords=['what','who','and','a','at','is','am']
query="What is hello','Ask in the community','my name is Alan and I am coming from London"

querywords = query.split()
print(querywords)
resultwords  = [word for word in querywords if word.lower() not in stopwords]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)

print (result)
```